# When is an object declared and initialized in a local reference created in Java?

Tags: java, classloader

If I have the following code:

```
public class Foo {

   private Object obj = new Object();

   public void bar() {
      final Object obj2 = new Object();
   }
}
```

- Am I correct in stating that when a new instance of `Foo` is created, the object referred to be `obj` will be instantiated?
- Also, will the object referred to be `obj2` only be loaded by the
  the JVM when the method `bar` is pushed onto the stack
  (invoked)?
- Finally, local variables live on the stack, to am I also correct in
  saying that `obj2` will live on the stack, while the object it refers
  to lives on the heap?

Comment: Be careful with your terminology - classloaders don't instantiate or load objects, they load classes.

Comment: Confusing terms. The classloader doesn't instantiate objects. The named variable in `obj2` is actually "erased" (has no name) after the compilation to byte-code. And yes, `obj2` won't be assigned a value until `bar` is called.

Comment: @skaffman whoops. I'll make that change. So, accordingly, a class loader loads the `Object` class. When the `new` keyword is encountered, what is responsible for creating an instance of class `Object`? In other words, is the JVM responsible for creating a class instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the case. Objects in scope of a method will be only instantiated when the method is called, while members of a class so declared will be instantiated when the object is constructed.

Comment: +1 Is the JVM responsible for actually instantiating instances of a class?

Comment: the JVM is responsible for allocating the object's memory and loading its initial values. So in answer to your question, yes.

Comment: The JVM is responsible for everything that happens while a program is running. The compiler turns your source code (`.java` files) into bytecode (`.class` files). While your compiled code provides the instructions that tell the JVM what to do, it's the JVM that executes those instructions, including calling the classloader, allocating memory, instantiating objects, etc.